# Initialize ng-admin module in a callback function

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

I'm trying to configure an ng-admin app. I'd like to load some data from a file before starting the configuration, however when I try to do this in a callback I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module adminModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'adminModule' is not available!
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Here's the code:

```
$.get('/api/schema', function buildNgConfig(data) {
    var adminModule = angular.module('adminModule', ['ng-admin']);
    adminModule.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', function (nga) {
        var app = nga.application(data.label).baseApiUrl('/api/');
        // ...
```

If I take the `adminModule.config` out of the ajax load callback (and use data embedded in the page so I don't need a callback) and put everything in the global scope, it works.

Is there something I need to do if I want to initialize the angular module in a function?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, got this sorted out with some help from a friend. The error is a result of Angular's automatic initialization happening before your module has been created. Having:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-view></div>
```

in your HTML tells Angular to initialize itself immediately. Deferring initialization in a callback means your Angular module won't exist and Angular's attempt to initialize it will fail.

Angular's bootstrap process is documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap), along with instructions on how to defer initialization.

To make it work with ng-admin, remove the ng-app from the body:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
```

Then in your app js, you can defer initialization. For example:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-admin']);
    myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', function (nga) {
        var app = nga.application('My App').baseApiUrl('/api/');
        var someEntity = nga.entity(...
        // add entities
        nga.configure(app);
    }]);
    // Now we can manually boostrap
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

This waits for page load rather than executing immediately, and everything is in the callback scope rather than global.